# dataframe apply with vectorized function behaving weirdly

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am constructing a dataframe from the following dictionary:

```
diction = {"a":{"aa":0, "bb":2, "cc":3}, "b":{"aa":4, "bb":5, "cc":6}, "c":{"aa":7, "bb":8, "cc":9}}
df = pandas.DataFrame(diction)
```

I am then trying to perform some operations on the dataframe by using the following functions:

```
import pandas
import numpy as np
import math


def applyGivenTotals(rowOrColumn, rowOrColumnTotals, rowOrColumnName):
  return rowOrColumn/float(rowOrColumnTotals[rowOrColumnName])

def piLogpi(value):
  if(value==0):
    return 0
  else:
    return -value * math.log10(value)

def someFunction(df):
  entropy = {}
  rowTotals = df.sum(axis=1)
  rowApplied = df.apply(lambda row:applyGivenTotals(row, rowTotals, row.name), axis=1)
  unSummedPis = rowApplied.apply(np.vectorize(piLogpi))
  return unSummedPis
```

I am getting zeros in the left-most column but I don't understand why.

To clarify, my expected result is:

```
    a         b         c
aa  0         0.159757  0.124915
bb  0.116675  0.159040  0.145601
cc  0.129692  0.159040  0.150515
```

But I am getting:

```
    a         b         c
aa  0  0.159757  0.124915
bb  0  0.159040  0.145601
cc  0  0.159040  0.150515
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) for elementwise process:

```
def someFunction(df):
  entropy = {}
  rowTotals = df.sum(axis=1)
  rowApplied = df.apply(lambda row:applyGivenTotals(row, rowTotals, row.name), axis=1)
  unSummedPis = rowApplied.applymap(np.vectorize(piLogpi))
  return unSummedPis

print (someFunction(df))

           a         b         c
aa  0.000000  0.159757  0.124915
bb  0.116675  0.159040  0.145601
cc  0.129692  0.159040  0.150515
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like I was using apply and applymap interchangeably even though apply is supposed to be used on series objects according to documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html .

Comment: @Aurgho Bhattacharjee -  Yes, exactly.